# Missing values While importing from Excel to datagridview

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datatable

I have a Winform app that imports an excel file to a datagridview.
It is working well but only one issue :
I have 2 columns in the excel file that are integer numbers.
If I change a value from one of that columns and add a char that isn't an integer , 
the value is missing in the datagridview.

I have tried to change the column's properties in the excel file to 'Text' as the column type originally is 'Double' , but it still doesn't effects the datagridview.

I also tried to make my own columns with the type I need (all as string) , and then clone the datatable and add the cloned one to the datagridview , but still same problem.

Here is my code when clicked on the import button :

```
private void btnImport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            #region Import from the Excel
            try
            {
                string pathConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + txtPath.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;\";";
                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(pathConn);
                OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from [" + sheetName + "$]", conn);
                System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();

                myDataAdapter.Fill(dt);

                System.Data.DataTable dtCloned = dt.Clone();
                foreach (DataColumn col in dtCloned.Columns)
                {
                    col.DataType = typeof(String);
                }

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    dtCloned.ImportRow(row);
                }

                ExceldataGridView.DataSource = dtCloned;


                dt.Dispose();
                myDataAdapter.Dispose();
                conn.Close();
            }
            catch
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error");
                return;
            }

            #endregion
  }
```

Comment: anyone ?? need your help please ..

Comment: Found a solution .
setting the provider with IMEX=1 Property.
"Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + txtPath.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;IMEX=1;HDR=Yes;\";";